# Python telnet switch connection closed

Tags: python, networking, telnet

I'm new to being able to telnet to a switch using python so please excuse me if I'm asking something obvious. I used the following script in Python 3.6 and it appears my telnet connection closes. I've been able to properly connect through telnet in command prompt so I am not sure what is going on with my script.

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib
import time

Host="192.168.43.10"

user=input(“Enter User name”)
password=getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(Host)
tn.read_until(b”Username: “)
tn.write(user.encode(‘ascii’) + b”\n”)

if password:
tn.read_until(b”Password: “)
tn.write(password.encode(‘ascii’)+b”\n”)
time.sleep(2)
tn.write(b”enable\n”)
time.sleep(2)
tn.write(b”admin\n”)
time.sleep(2)
tn.write(b”config t\n”)
time.sleep(2)
tn.write(b”int vlan 10\n”)
time.sleep(2)
tn.write(b”ip add 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.0\n”)

tn.write(“end\n”)
tn.write(“exit\n”)
line=tn.read_all()
 print (line)
```

However, after entering the username and password I get the following error:

```
"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\telnetlib.py", line 327, in read_until
    return self.read_very_lazy()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\telnetlib.py", line 403, in read_very_lazy
    raise EOFError('telnet connection closed')
EOFError: telnet connection closed
>>>
```

Comment: can you post an ascii dump of a manual login ? obviously before pasting the text here, change the user and pwd

Comment: How do I get access to the ascii dump? I've searched for the answer but only have found how to convert a file to a hex dump. I apologize for the obvious question.

Comment: From command line, use telnet to connect to the switch, and type the above commands. Cut & paste here all the text : your input and the switch responses. Note: if it works, I bet there are differences between the right commands and the above code.